# Brown Dwarf transcending past the sun with the naked eye

Tags: solar-system, the-sun, planet, venus, dwarf-planets

I seen with my naked eye in mid 2014 from Ca. right after sunrise a black spot in front of the Sun.I observed it for about a hour with my naked eye. Here is a picture that closely resembles what I observed, except the object was a third the size of the black dot in the posted picture and not in the middle of the sun but off to a angle.Since Venus did not transcend with the Sun in 2014 my speculation would have to say it might have been a Brown Dwarf.The link provided below of civilizations from the past documenting Venus transcending with the Sun throughout history could be observed with the naked eye,So a Brown Dwarf would be easier to see with the naked eye.The picture is from google and is the closest image I can give to what I seen.I have no knowledge of the picture and can not determine if it is real or fake.     [image]

Proof of venus or a sunspot seen with naked eye transending past the sun
http://sunearthday.nasa.gov/2012/articles/ttt_73.php

Comment: Venus crossed between the Earth and Sun in June 2012 and it was visible but it wasn't close to the size of the black spot in your photo, http://sierraclub.typepad.com/explore/2012/05/venus-transit-astronomy.html  Numerous photos if you google Venus transit across the sun.

Comment: the object i seen was a 3rd the size of the spot in the photo

Comment: Just a confirmation it is in 2013 right? Alike userLTK I had thought too that maybe it was Venus transiting.

Comment: middle of 2013 seen from ca, right after sun rise and the object was seen for more than a hour with naked eye. no media coverage. my thoughts were venus but apparently not. my next conclusion would be rouge brown dwarf passing by.

Comment: Venus never gets close enough to the Earth to show a disc to the naked eye. Possibly it's a helium balloon, but there's no indication of a payload. Since this isn't a picture of the actual object, there's really no point in even asking the question. When you see an object in the sky you can't identify, take photos with the highest optical magnification you have. Walk several feet parallel to the object and take more pictures with intervening foreground, then go in the other direction and repeat. After taking stills, take video, and comment on anything you observe.

Comment: @HowardMiller Venus could be seen with the naked eye transiting across the sun, a small black disk. See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transit_of_Venus

Comment: I suspect mild, and non-permanent, solar retinopathy causing an apparent dark spot.

Comment: You say what you saw was similar to the photograph. Can you tell us the source of that photograph? [The web][http://projectavalon.net/forum4/showthread.php?61298-Polarized-sun-picture-taken-..need-expertise&s=0b5232b87ea78b86d0a2c9c09600cf25] says that this is an effect of the ccd in a cellphone breaking down when exposed to the intensity of sunlight.

Comment: Was it something like this: [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/euPnZ.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/euPnZ.jpg) Just wondering why you have waited two years to ask the astronomical community??

Comment: What's the source and explanation of your photo?    Is that Venus?   

And on waiting 2 years, he joined this site 30 days ago.   So he only waited 28 days.  That shouldn't have any bearing on the question.

Comment: Yes the the new photo resembles what I observed better than the photo I posted. The spot is scaled correctly too, but not in the same position.The spot was more to the top left of the sun.And I did observe it right after sunrise with my naked eye.The spot remained visible for about a hour, then the sun rose and I could not look at the sun any longer.

Comment: @Mr.Cruz So you're telling me you looked at the Sun with naked eyes? And you managed to discern a dot resembling the transit of Venus?

Comment: Hm... It could be a UFO?!

Comment: This does not answer the question. It *might* if you said something about the photo, particularly *what it is*.

Comment: There's no way this could have been a brown dwarf. Honestly, if a brown dwarf had passed through the Solar System, we'd know about it.

Answer (score 2):

*Possibly* an aircraft or flock of birds, or maybe an insect really close to your eye, but more likely an illusion or misperception. It's not very "bright" to look directly at the Sun with your naked eye!

Comment: Not sure about this but I doubt you would be able to look into the sun and spot a plane flying in the distance,

Comment: I would have to agree with you there, I've edited my answer a bit.

Comment: you can look at the sun for about a half hour after sunrise. I did it for years and still have perfect vision.

Comment: Yea, I still wouldn't recommend it. I mostly just couldn't resist the pun.

Comment: @Mr.Cruz Perfect, apart from the black spots...

Comment: First I thought on a meteorological baloon but than I saw the trail of the aircraf (see the clouds on the left)... I think a Airplane may be that UFO.

Answer (score 1):

Although the picture is too low rez to be certain, it looks like the object is very nearly circular. Pixels along the edge vary from pink to dark blue, while pixels in the center seem to be gray to black.

Without seeing the original image, I don't think one can draw any conclusion from the image, but the fact that it's so circular and seems to be exactly centered on the sun makes me suspect that this is a photoshopped hoax.

FWIW, the bright feature towards the left side of the picture is a sun dog, a refraction of sunlight through ice crystals, and shows no indication of the black spot, which means that if it was a real object, it was below that cloud layer, rather than above it.

Comment: I ruled out a balloon, because you'd expect a balloon to be pear shaped, particularly if it was a hot air balloon.

Comment: If the sun was a orange the object i seen was a pea in relation to the sun.The object was black,circular and not in the center of the sun out to the side of center. The picture posted is the closest in comparison of what was observed.

Comment: <http://sunearthday.nasa.gov/2012/articles/ttt_73.php>

Answer (score 1):

Might've been a large sunspot. Quite a few have been naked eye visible this solar cycle. Apparently there were [some big ones in July 2013](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap130710.html) (APOD)

Here's a white light shot of the [full sun on July 7 2013](http://topics181.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=7886493&item=6984).

[image]

Comment: No way... A sunspot would never show that big for us. We can't even see it with naked eye...NO WAY!

Comment: I've seen them naked eye many times. Most commonly near sunrise or sunset, with a thin layer of clouds. With a dark enough filter, you can see them at noon. See http://www.ips.gov.au/Educational/2/2/1 or http://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-news/naked-eye-sunspot/

Comment: Yeah with some filter like clouds it may be possible. But even so they don't seem that huge. And they are not perfect circular most of time.